# Recharging CR2032 (LiMnO2) battery in a pinch

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium, battery-chemistry, hacking

My digital calipers take a 3V 2032 (coin cell) battery, they currently contain a CR2032 (lithium manganese dioxide). It's on the very low end of remaining charge, I have no spares, and no easy way to get any today.

I also have a variable DC power supply, although I can't use it to directly supply the calipers because I need to use them far from the AC power outlet. The supply allows me to set the voltage and limit the current at the same time.

Given that I don't care about this battery, and I just need to stretch it a little longer (i.e. this is a one time thing then the battery gets disposed of -- and if it ends its life in a small ball of fire and lithium fumes, I'm OK with that), if I just hold 3-4V across it for a while, can I give it a little bit of charge back?

If so, what's a reasonable voltage to apply to it (and current limit) and what's a decent metric of when to stop? Will I need to do it in intervals to manage heat or anything?

Or have I been living a lie my entire life and LiMnO2 batteries are actually *supposed* to be rechargeable?

Comment: Tip: "*if I just run 3-4V through it for a while ...*". You apply voltage *across* a device. The current runs *through* it. I don't know if you can recharge CR2032s but if you can you will have to limit both the voltage and current to a safe value.

Comment: @Transistor This supply lets me set the voltage and also limit the current, so that's a plus.  I don't know what the safe values are, though. Thanks, though that's a good starting direction.

Comment: If you've got a PC that you don't mind resetting the BIOS on, you could use the CR2032 battery from it temporarily.

Comment: @AndrewMorton You're a godd**n genius. That's 100% my fallback plan if I can't breathe life into this other battery easily.

Comment: Digital kitchen or bathroom scales are a handy source too. :^)

Comment: Wear PPE, there's a good chance it will go bang at some point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panasonic [CR2032 specification](https://industrial.panasonic.com/ww/products/pt/lithium-batteries/models/CR2032) says:

```
Nominal Voltage (V)             3
Nominal Capacity (mAh)          225
Continuous Standard Drain (mA)  0.2
```

I would try it with a 4 V source limited to 1 mA. A 4 V supply with a 1 kΩ series resistor should be safe.

I suspect that if the battery is flat that it may not recover. It might be enough to get you by though.

Comment: All right. Those are numbers. I didn't have any before and now I do. Works for me. Will let you know how it's looking shortly.

Comment: Yes, monitor the voltage across the cell as a matter of interest. If the internal resistance has gone very high you'll see close to 4 V on the cell. I've written a little about cell internal resistance [here](http://lednique.com/battery-plus-led-without-resistor/).

Comment: So this has been running for a while now; I *think* it's working but it needs a lot of finesse. Something I noticed is that if the supply voltage across the cell ever exceeds 3-ish (not sure exact value), then the cell voltage (with supply disconnected) begins to decrease. But if I keep the supply around 2.95 or so, the cell voltage begins to increase again. It's slow, though. It started around 2.51 and now it's up to 2.78, which is promising. Experiment continues. Target is 2.95 I guess.

Comment: Also I'll have to post pics of my setup later, it's so pro. I didn't have any resistors so I fine tuned a cup of water with some salt, lol. It's relatively stable between 800 and 1400 ohms depending on factors I don't understand but something is happening so I'll call that resistor a win, lol. I stopped monitoring the resistor value because it was a pain, though, and have just been keeping an eye on the supply voltage across the cell, which has been very stable.

Comment: If you'd told us you were prepared to do chemistry I'm sure you'd have got suggestions on using lemons, coins, vinegar and all sorts of other stuff. Well done.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. I'm accepting the answer because everything seemed reasonable but... I now think the cell voltage drops have nothing to do with the supply voltage. The voltage has been a stable 2.95 the whole time, and the cell will get up to 2.79 or so then drop down to 2.60 and repeat. I've seen this happen 3 times now. So... I don't have an explanation, something about the chemistry I'm sure, or perhaps there is some more advanced charging logic that might work but... yeah... I'm gonna leave it charging but motherboard battery it is. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I think I got it! I don't stand by this method but; out of frustration I removed the "resistor" and switched the supply to constant current at 10 mA; the voltage went to 15-20V but after about 60 seconds I measured the cell at 2.81V, stuck it in the device, and lo and behold, it worked. Dunno how long it'll last but... huh. Btw the reason I removed the "resistor" is the cathode copper was turning black and the water was turning yellow, and since I used table salt and don't understand chemistry I just assumed something bad was happening with chlorine and electrolysis so I pitched it to be safe.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. 15 to 20 V was definitely excessive. I would have been afraid to go above 5 V with current limit. You may have blasted some ions back to where you need them.

Comment: Welp. I'm calling it a success: I got about 24 hours of decent use before it flatlined -- not bad for 60 seconds of reckless ion tossing. I briefly considered trying to revive it again but... decided it was more humane to just let it move on to the afterlife. RIP battery, you were a gentleman and a scholar. 